# How to return variable in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I try to pass a variable to another function in google appscript, but it doesn't work as expected, could you please help assist ?
my code as below:

Code.gs file (reference by BPWEBS.COM)

```
/*
# CREATED BY: BPWEBS.COM
# URL: https://www.bpwebs.com
*/

function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
  }
  
  //GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY
  function getData() {
    var spreadSheetId = "1jBmIDQgK8jQQrSCfaLe8Y6w1raUFBegAlwwkZT-TAN4"; //CHANGE
    var dataRange = "data1!A2:G"; //CHANGE
  
    var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
    var values = range.values;
  
    return values;
  }
  function read_id(){
    var spreadSheetId = "1jBmIDQgK8jQQrSCfaLe8Y6w1raUFBegAlwwkZT-TAN4"; //CHANGE
    var IDRange = "data1!A2:A"; //CHANGE
    var result_id = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, IDRange).values.flat(1);
    return result_id;
  }
  //INCLUDE JAVASCRIPT AND CSS FILES
  //REF: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript
  
  function include(filename) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
  }
  
  //Ref: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/145428/#Comment_145428
  //Ref: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4
  function find_id(id1){ 
    var list_index = []
    var id_array = read_id()
    for(i = 1; i<= id_array.length;i++){
        if(id1 == id_array[i]){
        list_index.push(i)
        }
    }
    if(list_index.length > 0){
      return list_index.at(-1)
    }else{
      return "ID isn't existed"
    }
  }

  function get_range_by_id(id1){
      var row_num = find_id(id1) 
      var range_data = [getData()[row_num]]
      return range_data
  }
```

Index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
  <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
   

</head>

<body>

      <input id= 'id1', type="text" , placeholder="input your id"> 
      <button id="btn_btn1"> GET ROW</button>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
    /*
  *THIS FUNCTION CALL THE getData() FUNCTION IN THE Code.gs FILE, 
  *AND PASS RETURNED DATA TO showData() FUNCTION
  */
  /*google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();*/
  var temp
  var datatable1 
  var id_input =  document.getElementById('id1')
  console.log(id_input)
            function getdatafromserver(){
               temp = id_input.value
               var array1 = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data =>{
                  //const res  = JSON.parse(data)
                  //window.location.href = data
                  //console.log(temp)
                  //document.getElementById('link').href = data;

                      datatable1 = data

                }).get_range_by_id(temp)
                return datatable1
            }

  function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
        //CHANGE THE TABLE HEADINGS BELOW TO MATCH WITH YOUR SELECTED DATA RANGE
        columns: [
          {"title":"ID"},
          {"title":"Rating"},
          {"title":"Reviews"},
          {"title":"Book title"},
          {"title":"Number of Pages"},
          {"title":"Type"},
          {"title":"Price"}
        ]
      });
    });
  }
   document.getElementById('btn_btn1').addEventListener('click', async function test(){
      await google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getdatafromserver()
      
    })
</script>
</html>
```

I want to use the result of function "getdatafromserver()" - this function will return an array , and pass it as parameter to function "ShowData()", with my code above, it said "getdatafromserver()" is not a function :( . Could someone please assist on my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- `google.script.run` returns no value. Please be careful about this.
- About `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getdatafromserver()`, it seems that the function `getdatafromserver()` is not Google Apps Script. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your Javascript side is modified.

```html
<script>
function getdatafromserver() {
  var id_input = document.getElementById('id1');
  var temp = id_input.value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).get_range_by_id(temp);
}

function showData(dataArray) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
      data: dataArray,
      columns: [
        { "title": "ID" },
        { "title": "Rating" },
        { "title": "Reviews" },
        { "title": "Book title" },
        { "title": "Number of Pages" },
        { "title": "Type" },
        { "title": "Price" }
      ]
    });
  });
}

document.getElementById('btn_btn1').addEventListener('click', getdatafromserver);
</script>
```

- When this script is run, when the value of `temp` is included in the Spreadsheet, the retrieved values are shown in the table on HTML.
- In this modification, it supposes that your Google Apps Script returns valid values. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank Bro, I'll take note your comment above. The code modified work as expected